# Is there a way to do primary indexing in kibana/elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

I have a index named **myindex**, I have documents like name, age, sex, email, ssn ... 
How to do indexing with fields age, email, ssn ? Is it possible ?

```
 "hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "myindex",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "18YjOHIBw8OuH4sS1d",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "ARED",
      "age" : "91",
      "sex" : "  M    ",
      "ssn" : " etzpk23456  ",
      "email" : "er@gmail.com",
      "address" : " qwert ",
      }
```

I have thousands of entries like this... for faster searching , can I do indexing on any field(s)?

Comment: What do you mean? You'll have to expand your question - by default all fields are indexed in ES.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You have a lot of whitespace that should be stripped (unless they're only present in your example), but querying for `name:ARED` should work just fine. These fields should be indexed by default. You can quickly test this without creating JSON queries by using the `_search` endpoint with `q=name:ARED`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-query-params-q

Comment: Elasticsearch indexes each n every field. You dont need to worry about that. That's why it''s one of the popular search-stack today .